# WSGI flask problems 500 error

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I am trying to launch a flask program to an apache server and it works... kinda. I can access a test route that yields just a "hello" so I know that everything is configured correctly. However when I try to access any other part I get a 500 error. my first instinct was that there was a flaw in the program and it was crashing. So I ran it on Flask independent server and it works perfectly. So my question is why do some urls work but not others even though there are no problems in the other URL. please let me know if you need any more information.

This is my conf file

ServerName localhost

```
WSGIDaemonProcess Ellucian user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/Ellucian/
WSGIScriptAlias /api/matching-gift-policies /var/www/Ellucian/app.wsgi

<directory /var/www/Ellucian>
    WSGIProcessGroup Ellucian
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</directory>
```

The error log is a classic

> caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without some sample code and config or some error logs

Comment: Have you looked in the web server error log?

Comment: sorry I didn't post them right away wasn't sure if they were totally necessary for this situation

Comment: Enable Flask debug mode and see what actual Python exception is being generated. The SIGTERM message is likely unrelated as that would only occur if Apache was being shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that wgsi was eating my authentication. Not sure how I missed it but it happens I guess. Thanks for the help everyone. I had to include a tag to allow authentication to pass through.

Comment: The ``WSGIPassAuthorization`` directive no doubt.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is Apache is blocking the requests or doesn't forward them to your application. Since I am an Nginx user I don't know much about Apache configuration but here's what I found on the internet.

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName yourdomain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:(WSGI port)/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:(WSGI port)/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where WSGI port is the port your flask application is running

This a simple configuration that will (hopefully) forward all requests from Apache to your flask application. If it doesn't please provide your current Apache configuration file

Comment: wouldn't it also return a 500 error when I tested the simple page that rendered "hello"? I could be wrong but I just wanted to make sure